# .NET DataSet filtering

Tags: .net, dataset

We are using the .NET `DataSet` and `DataTable` classes to filter data. But we have two tables with almost 596,814 records in one table and around 10,000 records in the other. DataSet filtering using [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) is massively slow.

Are there any faster approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your filtering at the database if possible, especially if it is a web app. If it is a client app, do as many optimizations as possible - but it is always going to be a little slow on a half million records. Make sure your app communicates that it is working to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DefaultView of the DataTable and set its .Filter property. Much faster than Select().